# Remove auto focus on elfinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, elfinder

I have a little question : Is it possible to remove the auto focus on the online filemanager `elfinder` ?

Edit : you can test it on the official site home page : http://elfinder.org/

I mean : when the page loads, `elfinder` automaticaly get the focus. The problem is that I can't (for example) use `F5` to reload the page, unless I click outside the file manager.

I tried to get the focus on another element using :

```
$().ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("getFocus").focus;
    $( "#getFocus" ).focus();
    console.log(document.activeElement);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

```
console.log(document.activeElement);
```

is giving me :

```
<body>...</body>
```

Which is what I actually want, but the keyboard stay focused on elfinder.

Is it any way to do that without simulating a click on an element ?

Comment: Use `$("#selectorId").click();`

Comment: Thanks for answering Robert, but this is not what I want. Read the last line : `without simulating a click on an element`.